# linq to entities throwing some error

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

hi i am using this controller

```
public ActionResult gridview() 
        {


  var jsonData = new {
    total = 1, //todo: calculate
    page = 1,
    records = db.TestModels.Count(),
    rows = (
      from question in db.TestModels
      select new {
        id = question.Dataid,
        cell = new string[] { 
          question.Dataid, question.Name, question.Emailid 
        }
      }).ToArray()
  };
  return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
    }
```

am getting this error

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
can any body help

Comment: Your code example doesn't use to string at all?

Comment: @Sayse I suspect it has something to do with the `new string[] { ... }`

Comment: from question in db.TestModels i have changed this line to  from question in db.TestModels.AsEnumerable() now it is working but the output is {"total":1,"page":1,"records":11,"rows":[{"id":18,"cell":["18","aditya","cast@gmail.com"]},{"id":19,"cell":["19","anil","anil@gmail.com"]},{"id":20,"cell":["20","cast","cast@gmail.com"]},{"id":21,"cell":["21","revision","revision@gmail.com"]},{"id":22,"cell":["22","sham","adityakashyap@gmail.com"]},{"id":23,"cell":["23","anil","aditya@gmail.com"]},{"id":24,"cell":["24","sham",null]},{"id":25,"cell":["25","anil","adityakashyap@gmail.com"]},{"id":26,"cell"

Comment: @user2745765 That looks like correct JSON to me, and looks like how you specified it (`id = ..., cell = new string[] { ... }`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use `new string[]` in a SQL query, but that cannot be translated to SQL. You need to get the data you need from the model, and perform the conversion in-memory. Use `.AsEnumerable()` to indicate you want to do the following in-memory, and not in the SQL statement.

Something like this:

```
var jsonData = new {
    total = 1, //todo: calculate
    page = 1,
    records = db.TestModels.Count(),
    rows = db.TestModels
        .Select(x => new { x.Dataid, x.Name, x.Emailid })
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(x => new {
            id = x.DataId,
            cell = new string[3] { x.Dataid, x.Name, x.Emailid } 
        })
        .ToArray();
};
```

Comment: thanks for the responding  ya ...i got the result but i am getting a out put as {"total":1,"page":1,"records":11,"rows":[{"id":26,"cell":["26","sudarshan","sudarshan@gmail.com"]}]} can u say where is the problem

Comment: @user2745765 What is wrong? Looks good to me. This is the json that your controller action will return.

Comment: but am not getting grid view

Comment: That is a whole other problem. Ask another question.